# to build persistent and non-blocking web server

Tags: c

i'm supposed to make persistent HTTP web server which is non-blocking. so far i have used the select() to accept multiple request from different clients. can anybody tell me how should i code to make web server persistent??

Comment: What sort of "persistence" you are talking here about??

Answer (score 1):

Just never return from main() function, don't call exit() etc. And you may also use daemon() function under linux.